# SQL Select Count Statement

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, one for Employees and the second for records. I want to get total entries for each employee and order the results by max total entry like:

```
Daniel 3  
David  1 

tblEmployee:
EID Name
1   Daniel
2   David

tblEntry:
ID  Column1  EID
1   XX        1 
2   XX        1 
3   XX        2 
4   XX        1
```

Comment: This is a basic JOIN with GROUP BY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
select emp.EID,emp.Name,COUNT(etr.EID)
as total_entries from Employee emp join Entry etr
on emp.EID=etr.EID
group by emp.EID,emp.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `group by`

```
select count(*) from tblEmployee ee, tblEntry e where ee.eid = e.eid group by ee.name
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several variations on this, and you don't say what version of SQL Server you're using, but I like doing it this way:

```
;
using A
as (
   select  EID
      ,    RecordCount = COUNT(*)
   from    tblEntry
   group by 
           EID
)
select  a.EID
   ,    e.Name
   ,    a.RecordCount
from    A
    join tblEmployee e
        on A.EID = e.EID
order by 
        RecordCount desc
```

I like doing it this way rather than joining and then summarizing because you only have to group on the  minimum number of fields.  `EID` in `tblEntry` is likely to already have an index on it, while `Name` in `tblEmployee` may not.